# Any good way to have jQuery code assist in eclipse without Aptana / jquerywtp?

Tags: jquery, eclipse-plugin

For eclipse 3.5 / 3.6 and JQuery 1.4.2, what are the best practices for a development IDE?
(jquerywtp seems unmaintained, and aptana seems an overkill)

Is eclipse not the right tool for JQuery dev?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like eclipse + aptana plugin.

But if I had a choice, I'd use a MAC and codA from panic software.